# 'unable to locate ADB' when trying to run AVD - adb.exe in path, platform-tools reinstalled, and no antivirus installed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

This is the pop-up that the AVD-manager gives me when I try to run any emulator: [image]

I am 100% sure that `adb.exe` is within my file-path (`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`), and that I do not have an antivirus enabled. I have reinstalled the platform-tools several times to no avail. Any ideas gamers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my machine didn't have enough memory to run the emulator. This seems to be a unique case, but I'm putting this here if anybody has this same problem. Remember to turn virtualization on in your BIOs setup.